# Matplotlib add text such that it will end at point

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, text

I want to annotate text on the `matplotlib` plot where my text should end at given point. For example,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(1,1,"my text")
```

In above example "my text" will start at point (1,1). How can I make it to end at (1,1)?

I can always play around with points and manually adjust it, however, I want to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following,

```
ax.text(1,1,"my text", ha="right")
```

Which essentially defines the text alignment. More details can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html).